# Power of shortening in Powershell

Tags: powershell

when I started to make a big area ping request I first started to "write down" all the IP addresses down in an excel sheet to have a csv output to import it in powershell.

Then I thought about making those things in powershell more easy with less work to do.

```
$range = 1..254

$ips1 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.1.' + $Range}
$ips2 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.2.' + $Range}
$ips3 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.3.' + $Range}
$ips4 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.4.' + $Range}
$ips5 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.5.' + $Range}
$ips6 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.6.' + $Range}
$ips7 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.7.' + $Range}
$ips8 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.8.' + $Range}
$ips9 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.9.' + $Range}
$ips10 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.10.' + $Range}
$ips11 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.11.' + $Range}
$ips12 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.12.' + $Range}
$ips13 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.13.' + $Range}
$ips14 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.14.' + $Range}
$ips15 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.15.' + $Range}
$ips16 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.16.' + $Range}
$ips17 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.17.' + $Range}
$ips18 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.18.' + $Range}
$ips19 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.19.' + $Range}
$ips20 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.20.' + $Range}
$ips21 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.21.' + $Range}
$ips22 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.22.' + $Range}
$ips23 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.23.' + $Range}
$ips24 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.24.' + $Range}
$ips25 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.25.' + $Range}
$ips26 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.26.' + $Range}
$ips27 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.27.' + $Range}
$ips28 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.28.' + $Range}
$ips29 = ForEach-Object -Process {'10.10.29.' + $Range}
```

so I got to this point but now I'm stuck how I can make this even shorter without errors so afterwards I have one big Variable which stores all the ips in one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a shorter solution with the same result as your code:

```
ForEach ($Network in 1..29) {
    $IPAddresses = ForEach ($IP in 1..254) {
        "10.10.$Network.$IP"
    }

    New-Variable -Name IPs$Network -Value $IPAddresses
}
```

To get a single variable with all IPs:

```
$AllIPs = ForEach ($Network in 1..29) {
    ForEach ($IP in 1..254) {
        "10.10.$Network.$IP"
    }   
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what i wanted to do, as i tried to figure it out i was getting errors as i tried to do it in only one foreach should have thougth more easy thank you :)